# How to avoid sounds from overlapping when I press Next button using Fragments? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am using Fragments in Android Studio and each Fragment contains some educational lessons. I decided to put voice over in it so that the users can listen to the voice overs instead of reading the lessons alone. I use MediaPlayer by the way. However, when I press the Next button to proceed to the next page, the sounds overlap. The previous sound doesn't stop which overlaps with the next sound.

Here is my code:

```
package com.pau.papsirehv.knowledge;


import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    TextView next;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    Button btnSound;

    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        btnSound = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSound);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.two);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
        viewPager = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        next = view.findViewById(R.id.slideOneNext);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
               mp.start();
            }


        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

When I press the Next button, the previous sound should stop and the sound from the Next page starts. Can you guys give me some code to follow?

Comment: You should add the code so we can check the your current implementation

Answer (score 0):

You should change the media source or else create MediaPlayer every time next button press. Your next button code looks like...

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
           mp.prepare();
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
           mp.start();               
        }
    });
```

Comment: I still can't fix the problem. Someone help me pleaseeee

Comment: stop media player before starting new one

Comment: When I try to write mp.stop(); the next sound that is supposed to play will be the one that will be stopped.

Comment: okay, stop media player & start a new one with the new object